# How to generate Semantic UI offline doc

Tags: node.js, gulp, docpad, semantic-ui

It's been a long time I dident generate the docs (since `0.19.3` ), and it seems that the [doc was separated](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Docs).

I dont know how to generate the docs, because it is not well explained:

> Before running server you will need to build your UI files for the docs. Semantic UI includes a special command to build files for a docs instance that must be run from an adjacent Semantic UI folder. for example with a directory vendor -> SemanticUI place docs folder inside vendor to reflect vendor -> SemanticUI | docs

Can you please guide me how to do it?

From the [Semantic UI source](https://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui/), i run `npm install` , it installed all what needed, and then when I run `gulp build-docs` it generated a `docs` folder which is outside the source, this one, if i run inside it the command `docpad run`, I dont get the right HTML, because I dont know where to put the Separated Docs downloaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1706)

Just pick what you're missing to get it complete.
(It probably has some typos.)

A terminal is required.

### Assumed folder structure:

```
path/to/your/bull polished/project
 |
 `_ docs
 |
 `_ learn
 |
 `_ ui
```

### N.B.

All 3 subfolders `docs, learn, ui` may be given different names.
Subfolders `docs` and `ui` **must be adjacent folders**.

At the moment `learnsemantic.com` (`learn`) is independent of the other 2 repos. So it could be placed anywhere you like.

### Clone the repos:

```
cd path/to/your/bull polished/project
```

### docs:

```
git clone --recursive --progress -v "git@github.com:Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Docs.git" "docs"
Cloned https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Docs (http://semantic-ui.com/)
```

### learn:

```
git clone --recursive --progress -v "git@github.com:Semantic-Org/Learn-Semantic.git" "learn"
Cloned https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Learn-Semantic (http://learnsemantic.com/)
```

### ui:

```
git clone --recursive --progress -v "git@github.com:Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI.git" "ui"
Cloned https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI (The Semantic UI framework)
```

### N.B.

When you don't want to clone all the SUI repo history, read this : [#220 (comment)](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/220#issuecomment-68167168)

### Install Gulp globally AND locally.

```
npm install -g gulp
cd "path/to/your/bull polished/project/ui"
npm install gulp
```

### Install the Semantic UI framework.

```
(Still in : "path/to/your/bull polished/project/ui")

npm install
gulp
```

OR:

```
gulp install
```

### Install Docpad globally AND locally. Install Docpad plugins locally.

**Install globally:**

```
npm install -g docpad
```

Note: To update globally `docpad upgrade`

**Then install locally into docs:**

```
cd "path/to/your/bull polished/project/docs"
npm install docpad
docpad install eco
```

Then install locally into learn:

```
cd "path/to/your/bull polished/project/learn"
npm install docpad
docpad install eco
```

**Note:** To update locally (docpad and plugins) run: `docpad update` inside the `docs` and `learn` folders.

**NB**

docpad update purges/obliterates the docs/out folder (which was filled with dist and src folders, and files by `gulp build-docs`, `gulp-serve-docs`, and `docpad run`)
So when the time comes, run `docpad update` before building the Docs from the `ui` folder.
Run `npm install docpad` as root/Administrator (to avoid permission issues).

Definitely on Windows.

Sometimes also on Linux/OS X, if Node was installed "incorrectly".
But at least on Linux/OS X you can reinstall Node to correct this.
See: [node-forward/help#4](https://github.com/node-forward/help/issues/4)

### Build the Semantic UI framework:

```
cd "path/to/your/bull polished/project/ui"
Only if required:

gulp clean
Followed by:

gulp build OR gulp watch
```

### Build the Semantic UI framework for the Documentation in the docs folder:

```
cd "path/to/your/bull polished/project/ui"
```

`gulp build-docs` OR `gulp serve-docs`
    gulp build-docs : Creates and fills docs/out/dist and docs/out/src
    gulp serve-docs : Watches for source file changes in the ui folder and updates folders docs/out/dist and docs/out/src.

### Generate the Semantic UI Documentation pages and start the local server:

```
cd "path/to/your/bull polished/project/docs"
docpad run
docpad run : Creates all documentation files and folders (other than docs/out/dist and docs/out/src) in the docs/out folder.
```

### Generate the learnsemantic.com pages and start the local server:

```
cd "path/to/your/bull polished/project/learn"
docpad run
docpad run : Creates all documentation files and folders in the learn/out folder.
```

### When you're changing the SUI framework variables, etc

1) Make your changes to the framework.

2) Rebuild the framework:

```
gulp clean (only when necessary)
gulp build OR gulp watch
```

3) Update the docs:
    gulp build-docs OR gulp serve-docs

4) Generate the documentation pages.
    docpad run OR docpad server

Go back to 1)

If you used `gulp watch` and `gulp serve-docs` you should be fully automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the write up - really helped getting my instance running. What is the best method of implementing 'auto reload' to docs so if UI is adjusted, it is automatically rendered in browser? DocPad offers 'live reload' but so does gulp, so I'm wondering what's the best method.